# How to convert a column value which is like 20220401 of number datatype to 2022-04-01 in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, date-conversion

I have a column of number data type in snowflake that stores values like 20220401, now I need to convert it into date format. Could someone please help

Comment: I tried options like TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(BUS_DT,'YYYYMMDD'),'9999999999') AS INT  and SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(bus_Dt, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') but query is throwing below error 

Bad output format model 'YYYYMMDD' for FIXED: invalid numeric format keyword: 'YYYYMMDD'

Comment: Always best to read their docs.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html

Comment: Went through the documentation and tried above mentioned functions but couldn't get the valid output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select to_date('02/14/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY');

create table number_to_date(numbers integer);
insert into number_to_date values (20220401);
select to_date(to_char(numbers),'YYYYMMDD') from number_to_date;
```

More details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html#examples

Answer (score 1):

You can use to_date, but it works on char datatype, so first need to convert your column to char/string.

```
with data_cte(col1) as
(select 20220401::number)
select to_date(col1::string,'yyyymmdd') from data_cte
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet more way's of seeing/saying the same thing:

[to_date](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html) allows you to define [format string](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-date-time.html#supported-date-and-time-parts)

```
select column1 as raw_str, 
    to_date(column1, 'yyyymmdd') as as_date
from values
    ('19900101'),
    ('20220511');
```

gives:

| RAW_STR | AS_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 19900101 | 1990-01-01 |
| 20220511 | 2022-05-11 |

if you have string that sometimes are not following the format pattern you might want to use [try_to_date](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_date.html) as this will not generate an error:

```
select column1 as raw_str, 
    try_to_date(column1, 'yyyymmdd') as as_date
from values
    ('19900101'),
    ('not a date'),
    ('20220511');
```

| RAW_STR | AS_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 19900101 | 1990-01-01 |
| not a date | null |
| 20220511 | 2022-05-11 |

But given you said "number input"

```
select column1 as raw_number, 
    to_date(column1::text, 'yyyymmdd') as as_date
from values
    (19900101),
    (20220511);
```

now we have numbers, but to_date wants text, so we cast it to text, so the parser can be used.

giving:

| RAW_NUMBER | AS_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 19,900,101 | 1990-01-01 |
| 20,220,511 | 2022-05-11 |

Now if you use TO_TIMESTAMP which accepts the same format string, the naked number by itself it will think you mean epoch seconds, and give you wacky tiny number, like:

```
select column1 as raw_number, 
    to_timestamp(column1) as as_timestamp
from values
    (19900101),
    (20220511);
```

| RAW_NUMBER | AS_TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- |
| 19,900,101 | 1970-08-19 07:48:21.000 |
| 20,220,511 | 1970-08-23 00:48:31.000 |

which is all to say, cast it to string via `::text` or the likes, and specify your format, so that you can handle yyyymmdd or yyyyddmm or how every your data is.